# Update all Chart.js instances in order to apply changed defaults?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js, default

#### **Situation:**

I'm currently integrating a dynamic dark theme feature and need to change the defaults of [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) on a change of the theme. It looks something like this (highly simplified):

```js
function changeTheme(darkTheme = false) {
  if (darkTheme) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
  }
}
```

---

#### **Problem:**

The existing charts on the page don't immediately apply the changed default settings. Only on an update they do (e.g. on tooltip, change of data, resize of canvas).

I can manually update a chart by calling the instance method [`.update()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig) of Chart. But I don't have access to all existing chart objects (no access to scope of the scripts creating them) and I didn't found a way to get them globally.

---

#### **Question:**

1. Is there a way to force an update on all charts without their Chart instances?
2. or: Is there a way to get all the chart instances to then update them all?
3. or: Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and there is a way to fix this I'm not thinking about?

I would already be satisfied with an answer to one of the above questions.

---

#### **Example to reproduce the problem:**

*Show and run the code snippet. Hit the "toggleDarkTheme" button and click on "# of Votes" or something else to trigger an update.*

```js
// set function for theme
function changeTheme(darkTheme = false) {
  if (darkTheme) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
  }
}
changeTheme(false);

// button to toggle theme
let darkThemeActive = false;
document.getElementById('toggleDarkTheme').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  darkThemeActive = !darkThemeActive;
  changeTheme(darkThemeActive);
});


/* example chart, pretend like you dont have access to this scope ;) */
{
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          responsive: true
      }
  });
  document.getElementById('triggerManualUpdate').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    myChart.update();
  });
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.dark-theme {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: white;
}

.dark-theme button {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="toggleDarkTheme">toggleDarkTheme</button>
  <button id="triggerManualUpdate">triggerManualUpdate</button>
</div>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through chart instances dynamically using the `Chart.instances` object.  For example:

```
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance){
  instance.chart.update();
});
```

I've modified your example below to update all charts in the toggle function.  You'll notice that the font color now changes with toggle.

```js
// set function for theme
function changeTheme(darkTheme = false) {
  if (darkTheme) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white';
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
  }
  
  // Force updates to all charts
  Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance){
    instance.chart.update();
  });
}
changeTheme(false);

// button to toggle theme
let darkThemeActive = false;
document.getElementById('toggleDarkTheme').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  darkThemeActive = !darkThemeActive;
  changeTheme(darkThemeActive);
});


/* example chart, pretend like you dont have access to this scope ;) */
{
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          responsive: true
      }
  });
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.dark-theme {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: white;
}

.dark-theme button {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="toggleDarkTheme">toggleDarkTheme</button>
</div>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm. I'm so angry the property `Chart.instances` is documented nowhere. Not on the website nor on [GitHub](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/c9573bc1e4c3c00383742bf15764fd0e245cf885/src/core/core.controller.js#L1175)... but it appears in [this example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#printing-resizeable-charts); well this isn't helpful...