# Update all Chartjs instances in Chartjsv3 and v4 not working anymore

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I used a nice method to update my darkmode color changes in chartjs which I got from here:
[Update all Chart.js instances in order to apply changed defaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565630/update-all-chart-js-instances-in-order-to-apply-changed-defaults)

After updating to v3 or v4 the following line of code inside my darkmode.js doesn't work anymore and the color changes are not applied because the charts are not updated anymore:

```
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance){
    instance.chart.update();
});
```

I get the following console error: caught TypeError: *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update')*

I read the docs about all the breaking changes but I was unable to find anything related to update() in combination with instance.

Any idea what went wrong?

The upvoted answer solved my problem. However I would love to reduce code. Currently I call this function two times, once on initial load when theme comes from local storage and then again on the theme switch toggle. Is there a way to reduce this?

```
var themeToggleDarkIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-dark-icon');
var themeToggleLightIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-light-icon');


// Change the icons inside the button based on previous settings
if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark' || (!('color-theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
    themeToggleLightIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
} else {
    themeToggleDarkIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
}


var themeToggleBtn = document.getElementById('theme-toggle');

console.log(Chart.instances);
                        //Chart.instances.update();

                                // Force updates to all charts
                                Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
                                if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark') {
                                    for (let scale in instance.config.options.scales) {
                                    // Update axes grid color
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color = 'white';
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color = 'white';

                                    Chart.defaults.color = 'white';

                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor = 'white';
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor = 'white';

                                    // Update axes label font color
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'white';
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'white';
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    for (let scale in instance.config.options.scales) {
                                    // Update axes grid color
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color =
                                        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color =
                                        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';

                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor =
                                        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor =
                                        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';

                                        Chart.defaults.color = 'black';

                                    // Update axes label font color
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'black';
                                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'black';
                                    }
                                }

                                instance.update();
                                });


themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // toggle icons inside button
    themeToggleDarkIcon.classList.toggle('hidden');
    themeToggleLightIcon.classList.toggle('hidden');


    
    // if set via local storage previously
    if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme')) {

        if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'light') {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
            localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
            Chart.defaults.color = 'white';
            
        } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
            localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
            Chart.defaults.color = 'black';
            
        }

    
    
    } 
    
    // if NOT set via local storage previously
    else {
        if (document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark')) {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
            localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
            Chart.defaults.color = 'black';
          
        } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
            localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
            Chart.defaults.color = 'white';
          
        }
        
    }


    console.log(Chart.instances);
        //Chart.instances.update();

                // Force updates to all charts
                Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
                if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark') {
                    for (let scale in instance.config.options.scales) {
                    // Update axes grid color
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color = 'white';
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color = 'white';

                    

                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor = 'white';
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor = 'white';

                    // Update axes label font color
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'white';
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'white';
                    }
                } else {
                    for (let scale in instance.config.options.scales) {
                    // Update axes grid color
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color =
                        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color =
                        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';

                        

                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor =
                        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor =
                        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';

                    // Update axes label font color
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'black';
                    instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'black';
                    }
                }

                instance.update();
                });
   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chart.js v3 and v4,

Replace `instance.chart.update()` with `instance.update()` should resolve the issue.

Aside, there are also some codes that need to be migrated for example [Chart.defaults.global](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html#defaults) according to the documentation if you are working from Chart.js v1.

While I think from version 3 onwards, `Chart.defaults.color` won't able to update the font color for axes, axes' label as well. Thus, you should update each instance for the axes (`instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color`) and axes label (`instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color`) colors accordingly.

```
function changeTheme(darkTheme = false) {
  if (darkTheme) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
    Chart.defaults.color = 'white';
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    Chart.defaults.color = 'black';
  }

  // Force updates to all charts
  Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
    if (darkTheme) {
      for (let scale in instance.config.options.scales) {
        // Update axes grid color
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color = 'white';
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color = 'white';

        instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor = 'white';
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor = 'white';

        // Update axes label font color
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'white';
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'white';
      }
    } else {
      for (let scale in instance.config.options.scales) {
        // Update axes grid color
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color =
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.color =
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';

        instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor =
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].grid.borderColor =
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';

        // Update axes label font color
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'black';
        instance.config.options.scales[scale].ticks.color = 'black';
      }
    }

    instance.update();
  });
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3clevd?file=index.html)

Reference: [How to Implement Dark Mode in Chart JS (for Chart.JS version 3.6)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NV-8--_w1wY)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I would have never found this solution based on the migration notes! It works like a charm.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the code here. I have to call your function two times. Once initially when loading theme from local storage and then again when clicking the toggle bottom. I am a css designer and have no experience with Javascript. best regards